# How to use Xcode instruments to solve leakage in iOS hybrid app (ionic)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, instruments, hybrid

Hi I'm using Xcode Instruments to check for leakage in iPad hybrid app running on Ionic.

I've managed to capture a few leakage. However, what's the meaning of the logs?

[image]

The leaked objects are these, but how to fix it?

1) UIKeyboardTextSelection Controller --> UIWebSelectionAssistant addNonEditableForceTextSelectionGestureRecognizers...

UIKeyboardBasedNonEditableTextSelecttionGestureController